# The largest sequence of consecutive composite numbers lower than N

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, primes, number-theory

I'm new in java and I'm looking for an optimized code for finding The largest sequence of consecutive composite numbers lower than N for N=99999999.I want this program find that in lower than 1 min. The following is the program I've already written which find the sequence in 1 min for N=35000000.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=input.nextInt();
        int A[]=new int[n];
        int B[]=new int[n];
        int cA=0;
        int cB=0;
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            int c=0;
            for(int d=2;d<=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(j));d++)
            {
                if(j%d==0)
                    break;
                else
                    c++;
                    continue;
            }
            if(c==Math.floor(Math.sqrt(j))-1)
            {
                A[cA]=j;
                cA++;
            }
        }
        int M=0;
        for(int x=0;x<=n-2;x++)
        {
            if(A[x+1]-A[x]>=M)
            {
                B[0]=A[x]+1;
                B[1]=A[x+1]-1;
            }
            M=Math.max(A[x+1]-A[x],M);
        }
        
        System.out.println("The largest sequence of composite numbers lower than "+n+" is from "+B[0]+" to "+B[1]+" ("+(B[1]-B[0]+1)+" numbers).");
        
        
    }

}
```

Also is there a very optimized algorithm which I can replace int with long and it finds the sequence as soon as possible?

Comment: You would do better to set up a sieve to determine the prime numbers in the given range, and then find the largest gap which will probably be towards the upper end of the range.

Comment: I wrote a short java program (about 80 lines) incorporating the algorithm suggested by @rossum and it found the answer in less than 1 second on my laptop.